# Spring Data JPA query with optional paramters

Tags: spring-data, deltaspike-jpa

I have an GET endpoint which fetches the data based on the below parameters. firstName is mandatory and rest all are optional.

```
{

"firstName:"",
"lastName:"",
"Gender:"",
"city"""

}
```

How should i approach for the database query? i am using Sring Data JPA,
I have tried

findByFirstNameOrLastNameOrGenderOrCity(firstName,lastName,Gender,City)

Not sure if  a native sql query using @Query annotation will work as any of the values apart from firstName can be null if the consumer of the endpoint is not sending the values. Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

If you need something like this:

```
GET /myEntities?firstName=bla-bla&lastName=bla-bla&gender=1&city=bla-bla
```

> where `firstName` is mandatory and rest all are optional,

then you can use like this query:

```
@Query("select e from MyEntity e where e.firstName = ?1 " +
    "and (?2 is null or e.lastName = ?2) " + 
    "and (?3 is null or e.gender = ?3) " +
    "and (?4 is null or e.city = ?4)")
List<MyEntities> getByFilter(String firstName, String lastName, Boolean gender, String city);
```

Comment: @Cerp0 i have tried this query , but its not returning the results as expected , in my case i will be having only one record when all the parameters are passed including optional parameters , but somehow it is taking null values ---this is what its printing on the console bind => [male, male, null, null, null, null, firstNmae, firstNmae, lastName, lastName]

Comment: @VinayVullakula Sorry, I didn't understand what you mean ) Could you provide a detailed example (in your question) what do you need to achieve?